# jQuery attr() fails to set attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, attr

I am trying to rotate an image via svg's `transform`. This is the code I have:

```
<svg width="100" height="100"> 
   <image id="trns" transform="rotate(90,50,50)" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="logo.png"/> 
</svg>
```

This successfully rotates `logo.png` by 90 degrees when the page loads. Also, when I change `90` to a different number in firbug's HTML tab the rotation changes accordingly. But when I try to change the value with jQuery, nothing happens:

```
$('#trns').attr('transform', 'rotate(60, 50,50)');
```

What does firebug do that my `attr` line does not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working fine here (with jQuery 1.6.2): 
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/k3Grd/

Make sure to call it once the DOM is ready:

```
$(function(){
 $('#trns').attr('transform', 'rotate(60,50,50)');
});
```

Comment: The problem was the version of jQuery I was using (1.3.2), once changed it to 1.6.2, it worked.

Comment: @Edgar - Speaking strictly, it isn't. But, this, and your answer, led me to checking the version which was the issue. I then upvoted yours, and accepted this one ;)

Comment: @Majid You can always post the answer yourself, then accept it.

Comment: @lonesomeday - I know, though I am reluctant to. And in this case, I think a *working jsfiddle* **is** the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Very strange indeed, this seems to work

```
$('#trns')[0].setAttribute('transform','rotate(20,50,50)')
```

Also, if u look at $('#trns').attr('transform'), you are getting an object.. Not enough time to look into that now.

Comment: That indeed is strange, apparently `attr()` in 1.6.2 is sophisticated enough to manipulate the object in the right way. But with 1.3.2, which I used originally, it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jquery >= 1.6 try using `prop` instead of `attr`.
Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: How is that a property instead of an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

.attr() works in 3.1.1 like this

```
.attr({ style: "prop : val; prop : val; prop : val" })
```

this might be a way around version problems.