# svg rotate does not work with jQuery attr()

Tags: jquery, svg, transform, attr

I'm having the same problem than here : [jQuery attr() fails to set attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556368/jquery-attr-fails-to-set-attribute)

Unfortunately, the solutions provided don't seem to work.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var text     = document.createElement("text");
var dayLabel = document.createTextNode("test");
$(text).attr("transform", "rotate(30 0 0)");
$(text).append(dayLabel);
$(svg).append(text);
```

What I don't understand is when I look to the DOM tree (with Safari's element inspector) I see that the element has the `transform="rotate(90 0 0)"` set, but the rotation just seem to fail.

My jQuery file is up to date (1.7.1), and the code I showed is contained in a "Class" which is instantiated in this block of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... right here ... });
```

... so it is executed only when the DOM is ready.

Also, don't know if it can help but...

This piece of code works:

```
$("#schedule").append('<svg id="test2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><text transform="rotate(30 0 0)">blabla</text></svg>');
```

... but this one doesn't:

```
$("#schedule").append('<svg id="test1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"></svg>');
    $("#test1").append('<text transform="rotate(30 0 0)">blabla</text>');
```

Basically, it's the same code, but in respectively 1 and 2 steps. Once again, in both cases Safari's DOM inspector still shows the same thing, i.e. `<text transform="rotate(30 0 0)">blabla</text>`, but in the second, the element simply doesn't show in the page.

Comment: You should be creating SVG nodes (e.g. `<text>`) in the SVG namespace (i.e. using `document.createElementNS(...,'text')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$(svg).append(text);` <- do you have a variable named svg, otherwise it should be something like `$('svg').append(text);`

Here's a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zKWxp/)

I've set some text attributes and position, but otherwise it should be exactly what your looking for, I think ?

Comment: Yes, svg is indeed a variable (which is the parent svg element).

I tried to copy/paste your code (only removing the quotes around svg) but it doesn't work, i think :(
Nothing shows up on my screen

Comment: Well... I tried using your HTML too, and it worked. I guess I'm doing something wrong at some point. Anyway, I know it can be done, now. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: The fiddle looks good, but your answer doesn't explain what I think is the key issue here, which is that you're using `document.createElementNS` instead of `document.createElement`.

Comment: A last thing... I noticed it only works if I place a "<svg></svg>" tag in my HTML page. If I try to create it and place it in the DOM tree via JavaScript, it does not work. Any idea why ?

Comment: When creating SVG elements you need to use the NS functions to associate the elements with the SVG namespace, as the commmenters have made pretty clear. So to create everything dynamicly you would build the svg first and set the right namespace, then append it to your html document. Here's a modified [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zKWxp/3/) to show how that is done!